# Monte Carlo Data input (r script)

Tags: r

Could someone help me with the following code which will be an input into R following these instructions?:

Using R:

(a) Draw one thousand times from a `uniform` distribution with mean
`4` and variance `4` and make a kernel density estimator plot
(`plot(density(arguments))`) of the resulting values. (Remember, to find out about R’s ability to draw from various distributions, use `help(“Distributions”)` ).
Also, calculate sample mean and sample standard deviation.

(b) Now, using a sample size of `10` and `10,000` replications, determine
whether the sample standard deviation (calculated with `sd()`) is
*unbiased* for the true standard deviation (`2 = √4`, in this example).

(c) Plot the density of the sample standard deviation and comment
on whether it looks unbiased and normally distributed.

(d) Now, increase `N` (as in the example from class) and determine
whether the sample standard deviation looks consistent for the
true standard deviation.

(e) Now, do the same to determine whether the sample standard deviation looks like it is *asymptotically* normal. It is much easier to
evaluate the asymptotic normality of sample standard deviation (or estimators in general) if you graph the density of `√N(ˆθ − θ)` instead of graphing the density of the estimator itself. The square root of `N` prevents the density from spiking up to infinity as `N` goes up.

---

For part (a), I assume I am supposed to use `rnorm(1000,mean=4,sd=2)` based upon the info given, though I am unsure if this is correct.

I also did `plot(density(replicate(n=1000,Draw.bar(rv.mean=4,rv.sd=2))))` to plot part a, but do not know if this is correct.

I then would think to use `mean(replicate(n=10000,Draw.bar(samp.size=1000,rv.mean=4,rv.sd=2)))` to calculate the mean, but am also unsure if this is correct.

Comment: Sounds like you should have some starter code based off of the remark 'as in the example from class.' If you post some of that code along with an attempt to start answering these questions we might be able to help you. As is, I for one am not comfortable straight up answering your homework questions.

Comment: For part a, I assume I am supposed to use rnorm(1000,mean=4,sd=2) based upon the info given, though I am unsure if this is correct. I also did plot(density(replicate(n=1000,Draw.bar(rv.mean=4,rv.sd=2)))) to plot part a, but do not know if this is correct. I then would think to use mean(replicate(n=10000,Draw.bar(samp.size=1000,rv.mean=4,rv.sd=2))) to calculate the mean, but am also unsure if this is correct. I am not great coding and would really like to understand these problems, so I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mind helping someone get started with their homework, but I won't answer all the homework problems.

Given the part of the question that was understandable, this would probably work as an answer for question a.

```
sim <- rnorm(1000, 4, 4) 
head(sim)

plot(density(sim))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you also help with how to calculate the sample mean and sample standard deviation of that part a? I think that would provide a good enough basis to help with the rest of the problem

Comment: There is a learning point here.  Answer why the mean and sd are different than the mean and sd used to create sim.

Don't forget to click that up arrow next to my answer, then I get credit for the answer.

mean(sim)
sd(sim)



4.09009992620202
4.20052136000233

Comment: Part a asks for a uniform distribution, not a normal distribution. To find the two parameters you need for a uniform distribution (max and min) you can use the mean and variance formulas here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous). Just solve the system of equations